# Pycharm does not recognize functions in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, pycharm

l use Pycharm with python 3.5 and it does not recognize functions in tkinter.
error message is "Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:/Users/ömer sarı/PycharmProjects/tkinter/.idea/tkinter.py", line 1, in  import tkinter

File "C:\Users\ömer sarı\PycharmProjects\tkinter.idea\tkinter.py", line 4, in   sc=Tk()

NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined" .On python ,tkinter run good without no error.

how can l solve that problem?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

sc=Tk()
sc.title("DATA PRODUCTİON")
sc.geometry("500x500+200+200")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your file's name. Your file is now named `tkinter.py` and `PyCharm` (also any other IDE) confuses it with the module `tkinter`(since it is also named tkinter.py).